# Vectorizing 1D median filter For 2D Arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I vectorize the process of applying 1D median filter to the rows of a 2D NumPy array? Is there any way to avoid looping through the rows (0, 1, ..., 19)? My data is a time-series (25000 samples) from 20 sensors.

```
# Python
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
a = np.random.rand(20,25000)
window_len = 101
aFiltered = signal.medfilt(a, window_len, axis = 1) # seems like there is no axis option
```

My experience is mainly with MATLAB where I can specify the axis to which the filter applies:

```
% MATLAB
whichAxis = 1;
medfilt1(a, 101, [], whichAxis); % runs very fast, takes about 100 milliseconds on a laptop with a 3.0 GHz CPU.
```

I was wondering if Python can perform the same functionality.

Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
aFiltered=median_filter(a,size=(1,101))
```

Comment: Thank you. Would this be the optimal function for when the data is a complex numpy 2D array? Would you suggest the same function?